# PHP compare two multi dimension arrays and return difference

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 very large arrays from a product feed and i want to compare both and return the fields that don't match.

I've tried using array_diff() but it doesn't work on multi dimension arrays.

Is there a function available that does this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Comparing two multidimensional arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106001/php-comparing-two-multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: No its not, try reading the text body.. title is updated to reflect body more..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is function implemented in the comments of [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

```
function arrayRecursiveDiff($aArray1, $aArray2) {
  $aReturn = array();

  foreach ($aArray1 as $mKey => $mValue) {
    if (array_key_exists($mKey, $aArray2)) {
      if (is_array($mValue)) {
        $aRecursiveDiff = arrayRecursiveDiff($mValue, $aArray2[$mKey]);
        if (count($aRecursiveDiff)) { $aReturn[$mKey] = $aRecursiveDiff; }
      } else {
        if ($mValue != $aArray2[$mKey]) {
          $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue;
        }
      }
    } else {
      $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue;
    }
  }
  return $aReturn;
}
```